# Is 'Being bid for' correct English

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase 'being bid for' correct?

For example:

> All documents pertaining to the contract that is **being bid for**.

Comment: It might help if your example was a full sentence instead of just a sentence fragment. You may want to edit that.

Comment: *There is a contract. People are bidding for it. **That** contract is the one that's **being bid for***. The preposition ***for*** is essential there to convey the intended ("passive") meaning. Same as *There is a contract. People are **asking about** it. **That** contract is the one that's **being asked about***, (or ***...are looking at** it / it's **being looked at***, etc.).